# Sql server relationship using between value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have a database that contains 2 tables (`sql server 2008`):

> **LenderCommission**
>
> ID *int*
>
> Commission *decimal*
>
> **CommissionTier**
>
> ID *int*
>
> MinCommission *decimal*
>
> MaxCommission *decimal*

I want to create a relationship between the 2 tables. The obvious way would be to add CommissionTierId to the LenderCommission table, however this is then fixed. If the commission structure of a tier changed all LenderCommissions would need to be revaluated.

I'm no expert but I'm guessing that it's not possible to create a relationship where `Commission` is between `MinCommission` and `MaxCommission`. However, is there any way in which this relationship can be made more fluid?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve - you've started to suggest various approaches you might take without really saying what you *want*. Do you want the database to *enforce* that `Commission` fits into the required tier? And what do you want to happen when `CommissionTier` is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do - I've put together a demo of one way you might be wanting things to work. We actually create a table that contains more columns and then hide that behind a view with a couple of triggers to make sure that everything works well.

The tables:

```
create table dbo.CommissionTier (
    ID int not null,
    MinCommission decimal not null,
    MaxCommission decimal not null,
    constraint PK_CommissionTier PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    constraint UQ_CommissionTier_RangeValidation UNIQUE (ID,MinCommission,MaxCommission) --This is to support our FK below
)
go
create table dbo._LenderCommission (
    ID int not null,
    Commission decimal not null,
    CommissionTier int not null,
    _MinCommission decimal not null,
    _MaxCommission decimal not null,
    constraint PK__LenderCommission PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    constraint CK__LenderCommission_InRange CHECK (
        _MinCommission < Commission and --Inclusive or exclusive bound? <= or <
        Commission < _MaxCommission --Ditto?
    ),
    constraint FK__LenderCommission_Tier
       FOREIGN KEY (CommissionTier)
       references dbo.CommissionTier (ID), --This FK isn't actually needed
    constraint FK__LenderCommission_Tier_Range
       FOREIGN KEY (CommissionTier,_MinCommission,_MaxCommission)
       references dbo.CommissionTier(ID,MinCommission,MaxCommission) on update cascade
)
```

The view (which from now on you'll treat as your original table):

```
create view dbo.LenderCommission
with schemabinding
as
    select
        ID,
        Commission,
        CommissionTier
    from
        dbo._LenderCommission
go
```

You probably don't need this, but I tend to always put on an index when the view is masquerading as a table, giving it the same name as the original primary key would have been:

```
create unique clustered index PK_LenderCommission on dbo.LenderCommission(ID)
```

Now a couple of triggers that do some necessary house cleaning:

```
create trigger dbo.T_LenderCommission_I
on dbo.LenderCommission
instead of insert
as
    set nocount on

    insert into dbo._LenderCommission (ID,Commission,CommissionTier,_MinCommission,_MaxCommission)
    select i.ID,i.Commission,i.CommissionTier,ct.MinCommission,ct.MaxCommission
    from
        inserted i
            inner join
        dbo.CommissionTier ct
            on
                i.CommissionTier = ct.ID
go
create trigger dbo.T_LenderCommission_U
on dbo.LenderCommission
instead of update
as
    set nocount on

    update lc
    set
        Commission = i.Commission,
        CommissionTier = i.CommissionTier,
        _MinCommission = ct.MinCommission,
        _MaxCommission = ct.MaxCommission
    from
        dbo._LenderCommission lc
            inner join
        inserted i
            on
                lc.ID = i.ID
            inner join
        dbo.CommissionTier ct
            on
                i.CommissionTier = ct.ID
```

And now we populate them:

```
insert into CommissionTier(ID,MinCommission,MaxCommission) values
(1,0,1000),
(2,1000,2000),
(3,2000,3000)
go
insert into LenderCommission(ID,Commission,CommissionTier) values
(1,500,1),
(2,750,1),
(3,1500,2)
```

Now for some errors:

```
--This produces an error:
insert into LenderCommission(ID,Commission,CommissionTier) values
(4,500,2)
go
--This produces an error:
update LenderCommission set Commission = 2500 where ID=2
go
--This *doesn't* produce an error because the new value matches the new tier
update LenderCommission set Commission = 2500,CommissionTier = 3 where ID=2
go
--This is okay, we're adjusting one of the tiers
update CommissionTier set MaxCommission = 1550 where ID = 2
go
--This produces an error, because the cascading foreign key updated the values:
update LenderCommission set Commission = 1600 where ID = 3
```

---

As an alternative to the above, rather than having `CK__LenderCommission_InRange`, you might instead create a computed column that performs the same checks and adopts suitable values:

```
CommissionOutOfRange AS
  CASE WHEN Commission < MinCommission THEN -1
  CASE WHEN Commission > MaxCommission THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END
```

And now you can quickly search your table for values that are out of range (but nothing stops them from being created

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your goal.  There seems to already be a logical relationship between the tables; presumably, the commission can fall between the min and max values.  You would do the join as:

```
select <whatever>
from LenderCommission lc join
     CommissionTier ct
     on lc.commission between ct.MinCommission and ct.MaxCommission;
```

What are you trying to do?

One possibility is that you want to make this join more efficient by converting it to an equi-join rather than a "between" join.  Having the id would definitely do this.  If the CommissionTier table has only a few dozen rows, then this level of efficiency is probably unimportant.

Perhaps you are trying to enforce a constraint between the table, so new commissions can only be added with a commission tier.  If so, you can do the checking via a trigger.

Really converting this relationship into a single foreign key will be complicated.  You will need to take into account things such as:

- Preventing overlapping commission tiers.
- Changing the foreign key relationship when a commission tier changes (that is, modifying the data in `eaderCommission`.
- Maintaining historical data on the commission tiers, if you ever need to see "what it was" at a different point in time.

These are all possible, but are perhaps much more complicated than you intend.